# Access Provider resources from outside Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing the beginning of a card game where players must draw the first N cards and start playing.

My idea is to use a `Deck` that will handle all these processes giving/removing one or more `Card`s from owner's hand.

But, since can be a maximum of 6 players, how can it do it?

I was thinking to create one `Row` on the screen for each player and put here the `List<Card>` handled by `Provider` and `Consumer`.

With this kind of setup what the `Deck` must do is just to add one or more `Card`s to the line and it's all over. The problem is that I don't know how `Deck` can access to the `List<Card>` inside `Provider`'s `Consumer`.

I was thinking that `Deck` should create 6 global keys, passing them to each `Consumer` so it can access all 6 states but I don't know how to do it, this is what I wrote.

`Hand` class, handles `Card`s :

```
class Hand extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Card> _hand = [];

  void addCard(Card card) {
    _hand.add(card);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeAll() {
    _hand.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<Card> getCards() {
    return this._hand;
  }
}
```

`GameLineData` just uses `Provider` and `Consumer` for `Hand` :

```
class GameLineData extends StatefulWidget {
  Player player;
  GameLineData({Key? key, required this.player}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GameLineData> createState() => _GameLineDataState();
}

class _GameLineDataState extends State<GameLineData> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => Hand(),
      child: Consumer<Hand>(
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return Row(
            children: value.getCards(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And `Deck` :

```
class Deck {
  final Map<int, Key> keys = {
    1:GlobalKey(),
    2:GlobalKey(),
    3:GlobalKey(),
    4:GlobalKey(),
    5:GlobalKey(),
    6:GlobalKey(),
  };

  void giveCards() {
    //TODO
  }
}
```

Is my design correct? Any suggestion?